# Javascript Error: Returned is not defined

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hi there I am having an issue in JSP where I wish to call a javascript function:

```
<c:forEach var='item' items='${bookLogs}' varStatus="status">
...

<tr >
    <td colspan="9"><a href="javascript:expandOrCollapse(${sectionNumber}, ${item.type.name});">
</tr>

...
</c:forEach>
```

Currently I firebug gives me an error: 
Returned is not defined. javascript:expandOrCollapse(1,%20Returned);()

How do I pass in just the textual value of item.type.name ???

Comment: Quote it.. `&quot;${item.blabla}&quot;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with is a combination of jbabey and Salman A's answers.  I added the quotes like jbabey suggested.  But it sill needs to be HTML escaped like Salman A said, so I added `f:escapeHtml` function preceding the parameter and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `${item.type.name}` is a string and therefore needs to be escaped and quoted, properly. If, for example `${item.type.name}` is the string `returned "value" & more`, your HTML output should look like this:

```
<a href="javascript:expandOrCollapse(1, &quot;returned \&quot;value\&quot; &amp; more&quot;);">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the string or it will be treated as a javascript variable name:

```
<a href="javascript:expandOrCollapse(${sectionNumber}, '${item.type.name}');">
//                                                     ^     quotes      ^
```

You'll need to quote `sectionNumber` as well if it is a string. if it is a number, you don't.

Comment: This seems to fix it on that page.  But what gets displayed from the javascript running is "Returned".  So it seems "Returned" the string is being passed in.

Comment: @Ace i'm not sure what you mean, what behavior are you expected and what is it doing?

Comment: on the side of the javascript is was receiving the string "Returned"  instead of the string that was contained in ${item.type.name}

Comment: @Ace that means `item.type.name` has the value `'Returned'`, are you sure you're using the right property of your object?